# What is the cleanest way for a request in Laravel SPA

Tags: laravel, single-page-application

I'm creating a Laravel SPA. There, i have notifications, related to an user.

What is the cleanest way, to get the non read notifications for an user? And what is the way, that professionals use?

1. `/api/users/{id}/unreadNotifications` --- controller `$user->unreadNotifications`
2. `/api/notifications/unreadNotifications` --- controller `Auth()->user()->unreadNotifications`

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Poll the route regularly in intervals from the front end (not sure if you are using Vue, React, or another JS framework).
2. Make use of broadcasting with echo and pusher.js.

https://laravel.com/docs/master/broadcasting

https://mattstauffer.com/blog/introducing-laravel-echo/

For Polling if you are using Vue you can do something like:

```
  data() {
    return {
      pulseIntervalId: null,
      pulseInterval: 60000, // 60000 1 Minutes // 120000 2 Minutes // 180000 3 Minutes // 300000 5 minutes
    };
  },
```

```
  mounted() {
      this.unreadNotificationsPulse();

      ...
  },
```

```
  beforeDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.pulseIntervalId);
  },
  methods: {

    ... 

    unreadAlertsPulse() {
      const self = this;
      self.pulseIntervalId = setInterval(() => {

            // Do your call to your api here with promise if needed here, not sure if you are calling from file or using state management like vuex and updating the store that way...

      }, self.pulseInterval);
    },

    ...
```